# Add a Facebook login in my app delegate but it is showing some errors

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I am using Xcode 6.4.

I do not understand the problem.

> ld: 230 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

I have tried to add `-ObjC` linker flag also.

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)in swift

Any one help me please.

Comment: Which Facebook SDK Version you are using?

Comment: Sounds like you have duplicate references to the Facebook SDK. I would try the Sample Applications included, see if they run OK. If they do, then I would just try removing all references to Facebook in your real project, clean build and try readding once more.